# How could I control constructor access in another class

Tags: java, design-patterns, constructor

I created a class (ProjectsDataAccess) that will handle access to the database, this is what the class can do:

1. Receive Project object and save it to the database.
2. Retrieve project by id from the database and return it as a Project object.

This is the classes psudo code:

```
 class ProjectsDataAccess {

        public void addProject(Project project) {
          // get the project data from the object and save it to the database
        }

        public void getProject() {
         // get the project data from the database and return new project 
         //object with that data
        }

      }
```

And this is the project object:

```
class Project{

   private String name;
   private int id;

   private Project(){}

   Project(int id, String name){
     this. id = id;
     this.name = name;
   }
   Project(String name){
     this. id = // generate id
     this.name = name;
  }
}
```

My issue is I dont want the user of the class to create object and supply its own ID using this constructor `Project(int id, String name)`, but I only want the ProjectsDataAccess class to use it so it will be able to retrieve the data from the database (including the id) and then set it using the constructor. Is there a way I could change my design to do so.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to keep `ProjectsDataAccess` and `Project` classes in the same package and make constructor `Project(int id, String name)` **package visible** (without any modifers, like it is now). The other constructor `Project(String name)` needs to be `public` to be visible for client code. And of course put client code in a different package.

```
 package foo;

 public class ProjectsDataAccess {

    public void addProject(Project project) {
      // get the project data from the object and save it to the database
    }

    public void getProject() {
     // get the project data from the database and return new project 
     //object with that data
    }

  }



package foo;

public class Project {

   private String name;
   private int id;

   private Project(){}

   Project(int id, String name){
      this. id = id;
      this.name = name;
   }

   public Project(String name){
      this. id = // generate id
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

Comment: My only problem is that I have the Project class and ProjectsDataAccess classes in different packages and its hard to move it because the package that contains the Project class is shared between the client and the server.

Comment: But that's one of the main goal of packages: to hide internals from client code. If you see ProjectsDataAccess and constructor  Project(int id, String name) as the "internals" then they should stay in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to return a different interface to the user, only with the methods that the user is supposed to call.

For example:

```
interface UserProjectInterface
{
   void AnyMethodUserIsSupposedToCall();
}

class Project implements ProjectUserInterface
{
   //constructor won-t be no longer visible to the client class
   public Project(){}
}
```

Then return only the interface:

```
class ProjectsDataAccess {

   public void addProject(ProjectUserInterfaceproject);


   public ProjectUserInterfacegetProject getProject() {
     return new Project();
   }

}
```

This pattern has several different advantages, since you are not exposing the concrete type to the client class.

---

EDIT:

If the user is supposed to create the UserProjectInterface you could use a factory (es. [AbstractFactory](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory)), in order to encapsulated object creation:

```
interface AbstractProjectFactory
{
    UserProjectInterface CreateProject();

}
```

and provide an implementation that instantiate your concrete object:

```
public AConcreteProjectFactory implements AbstractProjectFactory
{
    public UserProjectInterface CreateProject()
    {
       return new Project();
    }
}
```

An example of usage:

```
//client class:
AbstractProjectFactory factory = new AConcreteProjectFactory();
UserProjectInterface project = factory.CreateProject();

ProjectsDataAccess access = new ProjectsDataAccess();
access.addProject(project );
```

Comment: Can you explain more, because the user needs to create a new project object and pass it to the ProjectsDataAccess.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it makes sense now. So what do you think about dcernahoschi solution, do you think using the factory pattern give me more flexibility or make things complex over making the constructor package private.

Comment: Well, his answer is right.Btw It depends on the complexity of your project. Usually using interfaces and factories is a good way for enforce decoupling of classes, and hiding concrete types. It has a lot of benefetis other than hiding your constructor.